# Cloud Firestore custom claims with query

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a firebase collection `notes` where each document has a `user-id` array that contains some user ids.

I've set a custom claim on my user access token that is in the format of `nid=true` (where `nid` is the note document id they should have access to) however when I try and query the collection for any relevant documents I receive a permission error.

My query is written as follows:

```
const notesRef = collection(db, "notes");
        const allNotesQuery = query(
          notesRef,
          where("user_ids", "array-contains", user.uid)
        );

        const noteDocs = await getDocs(allNotesQuery);
```

my security rules are:

```
match /notes/{nid} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token[(nid)] == true
    }
```

I've also tried `nid` without the brackets around it like so, but it still doesn't work

```
match /notes/{nid} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token[nid] == true
    }
```

Can anyone see anything obviously wrong with this? If I inspect my token I see the custom claim set correctly with the correct `nid` value. Unfortunately I can't find a way to test custom claims in the developer console.

*** edit ***

As a follow up to my comments on the first posted answer. The following doesn't work.

```
allow read, write, list: if  request.auth != null && request.auth.token[nid] in resource.data.user_ids
```

but this does:

```
allow read, write, list: if  request.auth != null && request.auth.uid in resource.data.user_ids
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firestore security rules don't filter the data.** Instead they merely ensure that your app is not requesting more data than it's permitted to. For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters).

Since your code is not in any way filtering on the `nid` token (as far as I can tell), the rules reject the operation. So modify the query to only request only note IDs that the user has access to, and then the rule you wrote can validate it.

Comment: I thought that's exactly what my "WHERE" clause should be doing, I'm filtering anything that has the users uid in the "user_ids" field of any document in the collection in my query and then using security rules to validate the authentication based on the token

Comment: Also to add to this, I currently only have 1 document in my collection, so based on the fact that it's "all or nothing" when validating my assumption is it should still return the result set as all of them should meet the criteria in this instance

Comment: I have no idea how to map from `where("user_ids", "array-contains", user.uid)` to `request.auth.token[nid] == true`, so I suspect that the rules engine won't know how to do so either. --- The number of documents in your collection is irrelevant here, as the rules engine won't look at any actual document for a list operation (as that wouldn't scale).

Comment: Thanks, as it was hitting the rules for the documents in the collection, my assumption was it was then processing the results of the query against the rule one at a time, so `nid` would be related to each document it loops through returned by the query. However I obviously have no idea how it works internally and whether that would be the case. I.e Collection has 10 docs, query would bring that down to 3, security rule then loops 3 times replacing the value in the path (nid) with the document id in that iteration. Then it evaluates the security rule.If all 3 pass it returns those docs.

Comment: I guess what I don't fully understand is why does this fail with a permission error:
`allow read, write, list: if request.auth.token[resource.id] == true`  (resource.id would be the nid in this case) whereas `allow read, write, list: if  request.auth.uid in resource.data.user_ids` does work - neither make use of 'nid' from the path, but both make use of the `resource` so it feels like it knows what document it is checking in a loop. Just one is checking if a token has the value of the document id and the other is checking the document for the existence of a uid.

Comment: #1 Your assumption is false and a common mistake. That's why I started my answer with "Firestore security rules don't filter the data" and a link to the documentation that explains that. For an operation that reads a `list` of documents (no matter how many results are in that list), the rules does not look at any of your actual documents. #2 on your updates, it makes sense that the second rule would work, as that `request.auth.uid in resource.data.user_ids` in your rules precisely matches the  `where("user_ids", "array-contains", user.uid)` in your code, so you're only requesting allowed docs.

Comment: Thanks, I did look at the docs, but I think what could be made clearer is that in a `where` clause the only things in the security rule you can use are those items and it doesn't have access to the full resource. In my eyes my doc set was already filtered by the where clause and I wasn't asking for every doc. In theory my security rule part was then just a sanity check. These things should always be in sync (the custom claims and the user_ids array) but it was in case a token was revoked without going through my cloud function that keeps these in sync. Does that make sense? Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, but we're not making progress here it seems. #1) your query failed because you're not passing the same `request.auth.token[(nid)] == true` information that your security rules check for, so it can't be sure that you're not requesting more information that you're authorized for. You may know that it's safe, but the rules engine doesn't and can't. I'm not even sure that check could be replicated in a query to begin with, so it might never work on a `list` #2) If you think the documentation could be clearer, there's a feedback link at the bottom of each page to let the relevant team know.

Comment: I get why it's not working now after your previous explanation. My last comment was  just a comment about the documentation and how I think it could be clearer. I'll use the feedback link you suggested. thanks